# Plotting three expressions on the same plot but in different intervals

Tags: plotting

I really need help with plotting the following expressions:

```
x + 3, -3 < x < -2

x^2 + y^2 = 1, -1 < x < 1

x = -2, -1 < y < 1
```

I need them to be plotted in the same plot, so the result looks like a the number ten.

Comment: What *Mathematica* code have you tried for the individual graphs?  If you have that, then you should look up the `Show` function.

Comment: If know how to plot each of them, you can combine the plots using `Show` (and setting `PlotRange->{{-3, 1},All}`)

Answer (score 2):

Gustavo's answer requires V11.1 or later. It can done in earlier versions by defining three implicit regions.

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}]], 
 RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[x == -2 && -1 < y < 1, {x, y}]],
 RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[y == x + 3 && -3 < x < -2, {x, y}]],
 PlotRange -> All,
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

The next time, please include your code (even if broken) so that we can know that you tried and where you got stuck. Otherwise your question might be perceived as rude.

I used @David idea of Unix box, but expanded on the use of Region:

```
Show[{
  Plot[{UnitBox[(x + 2.5)] (x + 3)}, {x, -3, 2}, PlotRange -> All],
  Region[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}]],
  Region[ImplicitRegion[x == -2 && -1 < y < 1, {x, y}]]
  }, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

```
Plot[{UnitBox[(x + 2.5)] (x + 3), 
               Sqrt[1 - x^2], 
              -2 UnitBox[x/2]}, 
 {x, -3, 2},
 PlotRange -> All]
```